# Stop detecting Input in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I stop detecting input from the user in Unity? I want to achieve the following: "do not detect `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`" In C#?

Comment: Please do not cross-post: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110940/stop-detecting-input-in-unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just "turn off" input from the  `Input` class Unity provides. Instead, at where you handle input, add an if statement.

Eg:

```
void Update() {
    if (gameState != GameState.PAUSED) {
        if (Input.getMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Debug.Log("Handle click!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to give an example without details provided by OP, but okay.